# Check string pattern in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

In my c# code I have a list like this

```
public static List<string> Teachers_Group = new List<string>
{
    "-RO-ANSATTE",
    "-RO-GJESTEANSATTE"
};
```

I have a where clause in my linq query where I check

```
bool amITeacher = domainUser.Groups.Where(k => Helpers.Constants.Teachers_Group.Any(k.FullName.Contains)).Any();
```

Now I want to check that the string to check have a pattern like

> XXX-RO-ANSATTE

Which means that I need to check that groupname has three alphabets as well. I think I need to use regex but I am not able to get started.

Any help?

Comment: Do you struggle with the regex pattern or how with matching against patterns in LINQ?

Comment: Both. I haven't used Regex before as such.

Comment: probably this regex: `\b(\w{3}-RO-\w+)\b` see: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5cw%7b3%7d-RO-%5cw%2b%29%5cb&i=xxx-RO-aaaafgg

Comment: If you haven't used Regex before, I recommend to first learn about the basics of Regex and _then_ use it in you specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your Linq Expression to use `Regex`

```
bool amITeacher = domainUser.Groups.Where(k => 
    Helpers.Constants.Teachers_Group.Any(t => 
        Regex.IsMatch(k, @"^[A-Za-z0-9]{3}\" + t + "$")))
    .Any();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBSF6Y)

Comment: That works but there is a small issue that it also returns true for AAA-XXX-RO-GJESTEANSATTE" which means it has the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

If Regex is what you are looking for then you can have something like `^([A-Za-z]{3})-RO-.*`

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to answer all necessary conditions without false positives:

```
  bool amITeacher = domainUser.Groups.Where(k => Helpers.Constants.Teachers_Group.Any(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "\\A[A-Z]{3}" + k))).Any();
```

Basically ensures that the input string is prefixed by exactly 3 capital english letters.